# Setting up PIA VPN on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up PIA VPN on Ubuntu Touch nexus 4 phone. I have checked the inputed data and it is correct no typos. The PIA staff pointed me to:
https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18003/openvpn-step-by-step-setups-for-various-debian-based-linux-oss-with-videos-ubuntu-mint-debian/p1

but it is not very helpful.

I have tried to input the same data as on my laptop and alweys get no success.

Comment: I wish to install PIA on my Ubuntu Touch tablet. Have there been any updates to the link posted? Would it be possible to install PIA via the taz  file that you download for your Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: I am trying to set up PIA on my phone too, but I am hitting a brick wall. I will be contacting PIA support and if I get any joy I will post on here too.